# WebGL gl.triangle make square

Tags: javascript, webgl

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
   // position
    -0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9,
    -0.9, -0.9,
    0.9, 0.9,
   // color
   1, 0, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 1
   ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);

  var size = 2;
  var type = gl.FLOAT;
  var normalize = false;
  var stride = 0;
  var offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  var size = 4;
  var type = gl.FLOAT;
  var normalize = false;
  var stride = 0;
  var offset = Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 8; 
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
```

This is some portion of the code ( the code is too long to fit ) so I will put these part where I'm curious about why it didnt draw a square but still a triangle? I know that I used gl.Triangle but I want to try using gl.Triangle to draw a square which I'm not sure which part of this is wrong and I have searched about it but no one do the same thing as I do ( the one where I put position and vertices in the same array )

There's also this part where count is 3 which I'm not sure what it does  ( this code is given by my professor to let me make it a square and colored by changing a few setting so I do not know how to code opengl yet )

```
// Draw the geometry.
   var offset = 0;
   var count = 3;
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, count);
```

below is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CS299 - Assignment 1.1</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- css override -->
  <style type="text/css">
  body { background-color: #CCCCCC; }
  #group {background-color: #E8F49F;}
  canvas { background-color: #4DC72F; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 0px; }
  .gman-widget-slider {min-width: 200px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

<!-- util functions -->
<script src="https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<!-- main WebGL2 code -->
<script>
  "use strict";

  var vs = `#version 300 es
  
  // an attribute is an input (in) to a vertex shader.
  // It will receive data from a buffer
  in vec2 a_position;
  in vec4 a_color;
  
  // color output from vertex shader to fragment shader
  out vec4 v_color;

  // all shaders have a main function.
  void main() {
    
    // default position output variable
    // convert vec2 to vec4
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
    
    // color passthrough
    v_color = a_color;
  }
  `;

  var fs = `#version 300 es

  precision highp float;

  // color passthrough
  in vec4 v_color;
  
  // outout color 
  out vec4 outColor;

  void main() {
    outColor = v_color;
  }
  `;

  function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_color");
  

  // Create set of attributes
  var vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  // Create a buffer (formerly called "vertex buffer object", now just "buffer").
  var vbo = gl.createBuffer();
  
  // Set Geometry.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

  // [40%] Modify the code to draw a square instead of a triangle. 
  // Assign C,M,Y, and K colors to the 4 vertices of the square. 
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
   // position
    -0.9, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9,
    -0.9, -0.9,
    0.9, 0.9,
   // color
   1, 0, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 1
   ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

   // tell the position attribute how to pull data out of the current ARRAY_BUFFER
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);

  var size = 2;
  var type = gl.FLOAT;
  var normalize = false;
  var stride = 0;
  var offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  var size = 4;
  var type = gl.FLOAT;
  var normalize = false;
  var stride = 0;
  var offset = Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 8; // must be in bytes
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene() {
    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas
    gl.clearColor(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Bind the attribute/buffer set we want.
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    // Draw the geometry.
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 3;

    // [1.5 points] Use gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP instead of gl.TRIANGLES
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, count);
  }

  drawScene();
}

main();
</script>

<p id="group">Group: 4DC72F</p>
</html>
```

I would like some hint instead of answer if that is ok because I was trying to learn but I cant find this method anywhere on the internet

Comment: `count` is the number of vertex indices to process.  You'd need 6 to make a square (out of two triangles with `gl.TRIANGLES`) not 3 (which would draw just one triangle).  But with only 4 vertices, you'd need to use a _triangle fan_ or _triangle strip_.   (See [diagram of primitives](https://www.3dgep.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/OpenGL-Primitives.png))

Comment: Can you explain why it is 6 and not 4 for a square?
Edit : ohh I think I got it  6 is 2 triangles and 2 triangles make 1 square

Comment: You also may have a **typo**.  You have the vertex `0.9, 0.9` in your list twice  (it's the 2nd and 4th vertex in your buffer),  I think you meant the latter one to be `0.9, -0.9`,

Comment: @Wyck That may not be a typo because I must admit that at that time I didn't even know which one is which but now I know but anyway Thanks! the count resolved for now but I will close the threads so I can continue to try solving more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your vertex specification, the coordinate (0.9, 0.9) is duplicated, however, that's not the only problem.

See [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives). The primitive type `gl.TRIANGLES` renders, as the name suggests, triangles. For 2 triangles you need 6 verticals (2*3). Each triangle consists of 3 vertices, and the triangles are completely independent and have no common vertices. e.g.:

```js
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
   // position

   // triangle 1
    -0.9,  0.9, 
     0.9,  0.9,
    -0.9, -0.9,
   // triangle 2
     0.9,  0.9,
     0.9, -0.9,
    -0.9, -0.9,

   // color
   // [...]

   ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

However you can use the primitive type `gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP` to draw a single quad:

```js
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
   // position
    -0.9,  0.9, 
     0.9,  0.9,
    -0.9, -0.9,
     0.9, -0.9,
   // color
   1, 0, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 0, 1,
   1, 0, 1, 1,
   1, 0, 0, 1
   ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

```js
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```